# How many irreducible components can an affine algebraic set have?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $X$ be an affine algebraic set, i.e. $X=V(I)$ is the zero set of some ideal $I\subseteq k[T_1,\ldots T_k]$. $X$ must not necessarily be irreducible.

Is there a finite decomposition into irreducible algebraic sets, i.e.
$$ X = U_1\sqcup \ldots \sqcup U_n?$$

Comment: 1) This depends on your definition of algebraic set. You should specify your definition. 2) Do you really mean $\sqcup$? For instance, for $V(xy)\subset \Bbb A^2$, would you want $V(x)$ and $V(y)$, or does the fact that they intersect mean you don't want this?

Comment: This was part of my confusion. So every affine algebraic set can be written as a finite union of affine varieties (irreducible) using the *Lasker-Noether primary decomposition theorem*, but this needn't be disjoint, as your example shows, yes?

Comment: @Lukas Correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing @KReisers and my comments:

When $X=V(I)$ is an algebraic set, i.e. the zero locus of an ideal $I\subseteq k[T_1,\ldots T_k]$, it can be expressed as the finite union of irreducible algebraic varieties
$$ X=\bigcup U_i$$
where $U_i=V(P_i)$ are the zero loci of prime ideals $P_i\subset k[T_1,\ldots T_k]$. This is a consequence of the [Lasker-Noether primary decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition).

However, this union need not be disjoint. Consider $X=V(xy)$ for $(xy)\subseteq k[x,y]$. Then $V(xy)=V(x)\cup V(y)$, where  both $V(x)$ and $V(y)$ are irreducible. However, they are not disjoint, as $(0,0)$ is a common point.